# Is it recommended to add a separate status field to check for completion or is completer id and date enough?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a messaging board where users can leave feedback and if the comments are completed you click a check button. I need to retrieve who marked it completed and when. Do you recommend having 3 fields (`status`, `user` who completed and `date`) or just 2 fields (`user` and `date`), since both of those can be used to determine if the post is completed?

Please let me know if there is another stack exchange forum where this should go, since I can see that it may be opinion-based, but my goal is to find out the most optimal way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have three fields, `status`, `user`, `date`.  In fact, you might want multiple rows, each time the status changes.

Right now, you have only one status.  It is not beyond the realm of imagination that you could have multiple status in the future -- "deleted", "in review", and so on.  In such a circumstance, the link between the date and `completed` would be broken.